# Can iPad communicate with embedded systems via RS232 serial communication?

Tags: ipad, serial-port

I have never used iPad. I am completely new to iPhone and iPad application development. I have a robot which can listen to commands sent to it via serial communication or through Xbee.

Can someone tell me if it is possible to write an iPad application that can send commands through COM port?

Comment: Does the iPad even have a COM port? I doubt there's an RS232 interface in the standard iPod connector.

Comment: Oh, and there are USB to serial converters which might be useful for this.

Comment: Accept answers to previous answers. Were none of them any good ?

Comment: I am using USB to serial interface currently with PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Long answer is maybe. The dock connector pinout suggests that there might be usable serial port hardware:

http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml

but you will probably need access to the Apple MFi program to use it:

http://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

I don't have MFi access and can only speculate that it might be possible.

Another option is to use the audio connector, though this has its own problems:

http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/01/project-hijack-uses-iphone-audio-jack-to-make-cheap-sensors.ars

Answer (score -1):

We have to develop software and an adaptor which can control equipment via ipad serial port. Your ipad has to be jailbreak

See : http://www.zonemicro.ca/zoneenglish/pivot/archive.php?c=About&w=&t=